# How to get NSURL to from UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I am using CloudKit to save the records that have been created by users. After managed to save string, integer, and CLLocation, next I want to save image to the records.

Within UIImagePickerControllerDelegate using imagePickerController function, I could get the info of the NSURL of the object, so I guess I could get NSURL from it:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
           imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    let mediaURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]!
    captured_mediaUrl = mediaURL as! NSURL
    print(mediaURL)
    var edittedImage: UIImage = ((info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!)

    imageView.image = edittedImage
     imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Then I'd figured I use the captured_MediaUrl to save in CKRecords as CKAsset:

```
@IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {

    var createdCoffee = Coffee()
    createdCoffee.name = self.coffeeName.text!
    createdCoffee.cafe = self.cafeName.text!
    createdCoffee.rating = Double(ratingController.rating)
    createdCoffee.place = savedLocation
    self.coffee = createdCoffee
    self.delegate?.viewController(self, didAddCoffee: self.coffee)


    //create the cloudkit record here
    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicData = container.publicCloudDatabase


    let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Coffee")
    record.setValue(coffee!.name, forKey: "Name")
    record.setValue(coffee!.cafe, forKey: "Cafe")
    record.setValue(coffee!.rating, forKey: "Rating")
    record.setValue(coffee!.place, forKey: "Place")
    record.setValue(CKAsset(fileURL: captured_mediaUrl!), forKey: "Image")
    publicData.saveRecord(record, completionHandler: { record, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }

    })
```

However, this return me an error:

> assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=76A0FFD5-84A2-4B68-BA2A-CEEC0F2C8B6C&ext=JPG
>      2016-04-11 12:55:37.918 CoffeeApp[1112:199929] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Non-file URL'

What is the right way to save image in CKRecords?

Comment: are you get the output from here `captured_mediaUrl`

Comment: yes, the captured_mediaUrl is actually  "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=76A0FFD5-84A2-4B68-BA2A-CEEC0F2C8B6C&ext=JPG"

Comment: then check here once u get file path or not  record.setValue(CKAsset(fileURL: captured_mediaUrl!), forKey: "Image")